# Iphone media query is not working while others are

Tags: css, media-queries

I got a couple of mediaqueries for ipad, galaxy etc. While those for the ipad and galaxy work perfectly, the iphone one doesn't. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My queries (in this order):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 360px) 
and (max-device-width : 640px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}
```

This all comes from responsive.css, I also have a default css file but that file overwriting the responsive one doesn't make sense because the galaxy and ipad media queries work.

Comment: I don't think you need to use all 3 of those queries. They're possibly conflicting with each other. If you just use the first one and remove the `and (orientation : portrait )` it should be fine for both portrait and landscape.

Comment: Have you got <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> within your <head>-tags?

Comment: The information is a bit unclear. Do you run all three queries per device, or the first one for the iPad, second for the galaxy and third for the iphone?

Comment: Posting an answer. 1 second.

Comment: @danjah , yeah I have.

Comment: @Jaques It is one css file that handles the responsiveness of my website. I want to target specific phones/tablets to adjust the styling to those phones/tablets. So each media query is for one device.

Comment: @twan Making media queries device specific is **very** bad practice.

Comment: @Jay , can you explain why? How else is it possible to target specific devices?

Comment: I think you just need to do a bit of googling. There are loads of guides on the net specific to this. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @Jay I see, but that website almost uses identical code to mine :P Only difference is the pixel ratio.

Comment: @twan Yes but you wouldn't include all of those in one stylesheet like you've done above. You don't want multiple queries being true at the same time.

Comment: @Jay So multiple css files per device?

Comment: @twan Sorry, no. As in.. You don't want media queries that clash with one another on the same **page** (not stylesheet) or you'll get conflicting styles.

Comment: @Jay so you recommend to use a page just dedicated to mobile, and a page to desktops? Isn't that a very old practice? You can barely call it responsive then, since it's another page.

Comment: @twan No no no. Don't use **media queries that clash**. Like I said in my posted answer about a screen with a width of 400px being true to both those media queries on the page. I don't know how else I can explain it to you.. The styles under both of those media queries would become active as both of the queries would be true!

Comment: @twan Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Jay Yeah, so it's better to just design your website and use mediaqueries for a larger device range.

Comment: @twan You need to just be careful with how you're using them. When 2 of them become true at the same time. The CSS within both of them will be used on the page. If an element is being styled by 2 different css rules. The more specific one will override the other. If the CSS selector is the same. Then whichever media query is further down the page will override the other.

Comment: @Jay Okay. It can be a lot of work though, to keep tweaking and fixing those queries when they are not specific.

Comment: @twan It certainly can. That's why it's good to work in % so that elements become fluid. I still strongly suggest looking into Bootstrap. It does lots of this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all those queries and replace them with just this one. It works in both orientations for iPad's and iPhone's.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

I'm not 100% concrete on this. But I *think* that your current queries are conflicting with each other. For example..

A device with a screen width of 400px would come under **both:** `(min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px)` **and** `(min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 640px)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but those media queries all have different css in them. So I can't just put all that css in one media query. Then ipad and iphone would have the same css, wouldn't it? I get what you mean, but that would mean there is no solution to target specific devices, while I'm sure there is.

Comment: @twan If your elements are responsive then they should be fine. Have you had a look into a 3rd party library such as bootstrap? Link: http://getbootstrap.com/. Lots of predefined classes to help with a grid system etc. If this isn't something that you can do. Then add back in the last line with `orientation`. **But**, I believe you may be getting muddled with the actual resolutions of small handheld devices such as an iPhone. The newest model (iPhone 6+) has a resolution of 1920 * 1080 which is larger than most old monitors..

Comment: But that's not the resolution to target in media queries is it? If I lookup a media query for the iphone 5 it comes up with a resolution (or better said: pixel ratio) of: 320x568

Comment: @twan If you're targeting them like that. I believe you need to remember `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2`. 320x568 is the logical resolution for that device. The physical resolution is much larger.